Reduce coverage noise in results when running Apex tests in VS Code
It used to be that when I ran Apex tests on a test class in VS Code, I would see one result per @isTest method.
More recently (I'm not sure for how long), I started getting multiple results per @isTest method -- one per class that's included in the code coverage. This creates a lot more repetitive content to scroll through.

I ignored this for a while, but now it's bothering me. How can I get back to the previous level of verbosity?

This output is used for code coverage. If you turn off salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage, you'll get just the pass/fail/compile fail status and the error message. However, you also won't get code coverage, so you'll want to turn this back on when you're working on code coverage. To enable/disable this setting, click on File | Preferences | Settings, search for the property name above, and toggle the checkbox.

I added "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": false to my .vscode/settings.json, and voila! Of course you're right about code coverage. Maybe I'm too complainy, but I'm not sure why reporting code coverage means having to output the same outcome, message, and runtime information for each class being covered. Even the coverage percentage for each combination of test method + covered class isn't that helpful, because it doesn't tell you which lines are/aren't covered by the test. Just me griping.

@MatthewSouther By the way, it's not "duplicated", each unit test method reports the classes/triggers touched in that method, their coverage %, the error, if any, and the run time. To find the lines not covered, scroll to the bottom, there's a listing. Once you get used to it, it's actually really useful information.
